# What is the method return type declaration for json in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In zend framework for APIs, I am using `$this->_helper->json($data)` to return json data

```
public function get()
{
   $data = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'xyz'];

   return $this->_helper->json($data);
}
```

Here I want to declare return type for this method. Generally for json_encode return type is string, but here what is the exact retun type to delcare in method return type.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have a nataive dataype for JSON, it's a structured string so your function is returning a string.